# Unable to validate passwordhash+salt created using php password_hash() using jBcrypt

Tags: java, php, hash, bcrypt, jbcrypt

We are migrating our authentication module from PHP to Java. Currently the password hash+salt is stored in the database using BCrypt algorithm. This value is generated by using PHP's password_hash() function. For validating plain text password, we are using PHP's password_verify() function.

PHP code

```
$hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //stored in db

if(password_verify($candidate,$hash)===TRUE) { //$hash fetched from DB
    echo "valid";
}
```

For migrating this auth module to Java, we are using [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) library by using [jBCrypt-0.4.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/svenkubiak/jBCrypt/0.4/jBCrypt-0.4.jar)

Java code

```
private static String hashPassword(String password) {
    String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
    return hashed;
}

private static boolean checkpasword(String candidate, String hashed){
    boolean matches = false;

    if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed)){
        matches = true;
    }

    return matches;
}
```

However, the passwordhash+salt generated from php is not being validated in java. For the string 'abcd' , the hash+salt generated is

`PHP - $2y$10$SA4iLMAniuNO6p9P1ZJElePaJvlN5eHGZ2dDt2Mutle4FQr1OY4hC`

`Java - $2a$10$YnqJT5NPCPTI8qKBbLfgIOIOW4eckdbE1R85tJGNRUJKmxz1TLkWG`

When I tried matching the string generated using PHP in Java using

```
 if (BCrypt.checkpw("abcd", "$2y$10$SA4iLMAniuNO6p9P1ZJElePaJvlN5eHGZ2dDt2Mutle4FQr1OY4hC")){
    matches = true;
}
```

I was getting the below

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt revision
>       at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:665)
>       at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:764)...`

How do I make both compatible ?

Answer (score 1):

The hash generated by `password_hash()` in PHP includes the salt. Which means when you're checking it against the plain-text password, the same salt is used to generate a hash against the plain-text password, and the two hashes are compared in a *constant time manner* for verification.

What you're doing in Java is generating a different salt each time, which means you can't compare the two. Your Java implementation is using a different version, denoted by the `$2a$` in your hash. Notice PHP is using `$2y$` and the salts are clearly different.

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/crypt)

> Versions of PHP before 5.3.7 only support "`$2a$`" as the salt prefix: PHP 5.3.7 introduced the new prefixes to fix a security weakness in the Blowfish implementation. Please refer to [» this document](http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php) for full details of the security fix, but to summarise, developers targeting only PHP 5.3.7 and later should use "`$2y$`" in preference to "`$2a$`".

So you shouldn't be generating a new hash in Java to validate the existing hash that was generated by PHP and stored in your database. Instead, supply the stored hash to `BCrypt.checkpasword` for validation.

Comment: I am not creating a new hash while validating. I am using the existing hash from the DB and comparing with the plain text entered by the user. I have edited the question with the exact code I am using.

Comment: OK, sorry, in the question the code you included made it seem like you were calling `hashPassword`. In any case, it's possible that your Java implementation just doesn't like the `$2y$` identifier. Try replacing it with `$2a$` in Java before you send it to `checkpw` and see if that works. This shouldn't break anything, but if it does maybe take a look at this https://github.com/codebazz/jbcrypt/